# How to print my map<pair<int,int>, pair<int,int>> in cout

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    map<pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>> items;

    items.insert(make_pair(1,20),make_pair(0,0));
    items.insert(make_pair(2,10),make_pair(0,0));
    items.insert(make_pair(3,30),make_pair(0,0));
    items.insert(make_pair(4,5),make_pair(0,0));
    items.insert(make_pair(5,35),make_pair(0,0));

    map<pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
    cout<<"Class ID:\t\t\tSamples:\t\t\tTP:\t\t\tPrecision:"<<endl;
    for(it = items.begin();it!=items.end();++it)
    {
        cout<<(it->first).first<<"\t\t\t"<<(it->first).second<<"\t\t\t"<<(it->second).first<<"\t\t\t"<<(it->second).second<<endl;
    }
}
```

I have a code like this but i can't print my values. Can someone help me please?

I'm getting interesting compiler error :

[image: Here is the image]

Here is the text of the error :

```
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/map:60,
from C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\quiz3\main.cpp:2:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(_II, _II) [with _InputIterator = std::pair<int, int>; _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >]':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:893:4:   required from 'void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::pair<int, int>; _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Tp = std::pair<int, int>; _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >]'
C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\quiz3\main.cpp:10:48:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:2467:28: error: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'std::pair<int, int>')
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
                            ^~~~~~~~~
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:2468:29: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::pair<int, int>')
    _M_insert_unique_(end(), *__first, __an);
                             ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I think we are all interested in this "interesting" error

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qc33pa

Comment: here is the screenshot of the error

Comment: please include the error message as text in the question

Comment: not the problem: `main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: the text on the image is hardly readable, please include it as text

Comment: i tried int main() but it didnt work

Comment: [`map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) has several different overloads, which one do you want to call?

Comment: i got the answer thank you :) The wrong thing is implementation of insert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::map::insert` takes a parameter of `value_type` which is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.  That means you need to combine `make_pair(1,20),make_pair(0,0)` into a single parameter so you can call the function.  That would look like

```
items.insert({make_pair(1,20),make_pair(0,0)});
//           ^curly braces create value_type^
items.insert({make_pair(2,10),make_pair(0,0)});
items.insert({make_pair(3,30),make_pair(0,0)});
items.insert({make_pair(4,5),make_pair(0,0)});
items.insert({make_pair(5,35),make_pair(0,0)});
```

Alternatively you can use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) which will take parameters to construct a `value_type`.  That lets you get away without using the curly braces and looks like

```
items.emplace(make_pair(1,20),make_pair(0,0));
items.emplace(make_pair(2,10),make_pair(0,0));
items.emplace(make_pair(3,30),make_pair(0,0));
items.emplace(make_pair(4,5),make_pair(0,0));
items.emplace(make_pair(5,35),make_pair(0,0));
```

Comment: Or `emplace` to get perhaps more intuitive behaviour!

Comment: replacing `make_pair` with braces makes the code a bit simpler